# enterprise wiki customization office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I need to customize the enterprise wiki so that each article can have comments against it.

The Enterprise wiki is basically a publishing layout page .Can I add the blog web parts to the enterprise wiki page layout page. But can I save the site as a site template and upload the solution.

Is there a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit EnterpriseWiki page layout and add a Note Board web part.

```
<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentWebPart id="noteboard" ChromeType="None" runat="server" />
```

This should be placed after

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="PageContent" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" MinimumEditHeight="400px" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>
```

You can save the site as template and use it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. it is a very good option. Instead of adding the note board web part can I add the discussion web part or the posts web part.

Comment: @user1339913 yes you can add the web part of your choice.