# Add Noteboard webpart to Enterprise wiki in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, office-web-apps, office-365-develop-tool

I followed this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118751/enterprise-wiki-customization-office-365) and added the

`<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="PageContent" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" MinimumEditHeight="400px" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>`

to the enterprise wiki page. It works fine on Premises. But in Office 365 it does not appear. It seems like that control has been disabled my Microsoft to promote Yammer.

Can some one show me an example how I can either create an **SocialComments WebPart** or wrap the **Socialcomments WebPart** in another WebPart and add it to the layout page.

Comment: Instead of Note Board you can add a script editor webpart and include the JavaScript as explained [here](http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2014/10/how-to-replace-the-note-board-web-part-with-yammer/).

Answer (score 1):

I think Yammer is the only option

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/SharePoint-Online-Tags-Notes-feature-retired-77851bd5-6d5e-42fe-9bf6-d7c17eeb771f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I can't use Yammer as it is very complicated .  Can I not create a control with similar to the note board functionality and attach it to the enterprise wiki .      1) How do I attach the control to the enterprise wiki 2) do I need to create the control as an app part or create a solution