# SharePoint Online/365 - Add Comments to Enterprise Wiki

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-wiki, comments

Are there any other ways to add a comment/discussion board type section below each Enterprise Wiki page? I found this [page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118751/enterprise-wiki-customization-office-365) but I thought Noteboard is no longer supported in O365/SharePoint Online. We also don't have Yammer approved by our ISO so can't use Yammer.

Comment: I have the same question and hope that somebody can give a hint.

Comment: I ve inspected the structure of SharePoint Online blog site and found that comments there reside in special list with comments. Maybe it is possible to make hybrid of two site types?

Comment: Interesting approach is offered on this on this question.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118751/enterprise-wiki-customization-office-365

Comment: Thanks Boris, but that's the same page I linked on my above post

Comment: Sorry. I was just running search on my own but found no solution evidently. Somebody with better insights than we have, please advise!